# How can I tell if my new AC is overloading my home electric service?

Tags: electrical, air-conditioning, heat-pump

I just installed a mini-split A/C system. It is 2 outdoor compressor units and 7 indoor head units. (I did 95% of the install myself, toot toot)

It was working great, but the weather had been unseasonably mild until now. (Install was done May 1, and then thru June 30, 2018, in Baltimore, MD, we had nothing but cool temps and rain)

Recently, i.e. last two days, we've been hit with a heat wave.

Also, recently, I've had three "brownout" events where the lights flickered, and power cut out in the house long enough to disrupt computers, tvs, etc. The first of these events was pretty coincidental with the start of the heat wave.

The circuit breakers did not trip. None of them, not the individual breakers or the mains.

How can I tell if my AC units are causing this or if it isn't just a general service problem from our provider?

I've tried the following:

- Shut off all the A/C units and wait to see if the flicker happens. (this is tough though since you can't prove a negative)
- Called my provider and asked them to check our lines. They reported no outages or brownouts in our area
- Checked all the circuit breakers

**Edit: Additional specs**

My electrical service specs are

- 200 Amp main

The breakers are

- 1 X 50A line for the dryer
- 1 X 40A line for the stove
- 3 X 30A lines for the 2 A/C compressors and something else, I'm not sure what. Clothes washer maybe?
- 29 X 15A lines for lights/outlets

That seems like a lot -- but there are still two empty slots in the panel. Although I know I shouldn't have the panel maxed out.

I'm trying to figure out how to do a load calculation to get a better idea but haven't found very good instructions on that.

**Edit**
Spoke with neighbors in my area. There are multiple reports of lights flickering like I experienced. I'm chalking this up to the utility provider having trouble handling the spike in load this week. Also, I'm gonna buy a couple of UPSes for sensitive devices in my home.

I realize these anecdotes from my neighborhood don't prove for certain that my new A/C units are not the problem. When I am able to, and get the equipment to, perform amperage measurements, I'll take that advice and get detailed electrical information. I'd like to have that information for myself, at any rate. It seems like a good thing for any homeowner to know about their home.

Comment: Have you experienced these issues with the mini-split system entirely powered off? (You mention testing it, but you didn't say if it happened or not)

Comment: when the minispilts are powered off this doesn't seem to happen. but it isn't clear; i turned them off and it happened again about a minute later, but the compressor could have still been drawin power even though the heads were off. I'm just not sure.

Comment: Did you turn the units off at the breaker?

Comment: no, but that's a good idea

Comment: What is your service rating 200 A? 150? What kind of panel? What circuits are the units on? Each on a 20 A 240 V?

Comment: @JDS, I'm also located in the area of the same heat wave.  Our local utility warned people in advance of the expected load on the grid, asking people to take various steps to reduce peak loads.  If you aren't popping your own breakers, it's more likely brownouts by the utility trying to meet the demands.  Their report of no brownout probably means they didn't purposely reduce power for a prolonged period, but momentary peak demands by users could result in brief, unscheduled brownouts.

Comment: Is your water heater electric or gas? And that 50A breaker probably isn't the dryer breaker....also, how many of the circuits in your house feed kitchen countertop receptacles?

Comment: It sound to me like a possible loose main lug and/or meter can lug.  Do you have conventional meters or smart meters?  Power utilities that have moved to smart metering systems have a trove of outage/brownout data now that didn’t used to exist, but they still can’t really see instantaneous drops like a loose or burning lug in the meter can or main breaker.  If they didn’t actually come out and check the inside of the meter I would try to get them to do just that.  Have you asked your neighbors on both sides or behind you if they’ve had such problems?

Comment: Btw, my guess is your dryer is not 50amp, that’s more likely the stove.  Most American cloths dryers have been 30 amp for many years.  Cloths washers usually aren’t 220v loads.

Comment: @Tysonour house is situated in a weird way such that we don't really have "neighbors". also, idk if the service provider has been out or not; they said they'd send someone to look but i haven't seen a truck on the street.
ThreePhaseEel 2 kitchen counter receptacles. we have an oil heated water heater (and oil furnace and radiators) (that's why I added the mini splits -- no ducts)
fixer1234: thanks, that's interesting. I'll look around for more info

Comment: @JDS -- can you get to the bottom of what's going on with that dryer circuit and the extra 30A breaker?

Comment: I suspect loose or burning connections on power companies side.

Comment: With the lights flickering it is probably the utility switching feeds. Mini splits are fairly low draw compared to central units and the chance that both compressors are kicking on to full power at the same time is a little unlikely. larger central units may cause a dimming, The inside units are basically fans and these don't draw much either. Based on the loads you provided I would be looking at the problem being caused from utility switching. I see this during high demand periods but my plant is the largest load for our utility.

Answer (score 1):

**WHY WE CAN'T ANSWER THIS QUESTION**
Welcome to stackexchange JDS. The problem everyone is having with your question is that you have given an excellent physical description of your problem, but almost no electrical information. To truly answer:

**`How can I tell if my new AC is overloading my home electric service?`**

We need to get the operating amperage of your AC. Then for us to try and assist in the rest of your dialog, we need to get information using and Ammeter and probably a Multimeter that gives us voltage in 1/1000 increments. Otherwise the best we can do is try to figure out if it is a utility brownout or your panel brownout.

I have attached a Panel Report and Checklist. Look at it and try fill out as much as you can so we can see what you are looking at electrical wise. Remember all of this will do no good if we cannot get at least the circuit number, what it serves, breaker size and amperes which are the first four columns from outside to inside. Also look down at the Buss Inspection area and check off what you can, and add anything that looks funny in comments.

[image]

I know it looks like a lot but fill out what you can and we will see what we can do.

Stay safe you will be working around live equipment.

Comment: thanks. this is the kind of answer i was hoping for, as indicated by "how can i tell..."